# How to write into excel dynamically using xlsx writer

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, xlsxwriter

I want to write data dynamically to excel file using xlsx writer . I fetched data from mysql db and the result look like below metined.

```
data  = (
    ('Shankar', '100', '100', '200'),
    ('Kumar', '50', '80', '130'),
    ('Shiva', '20', '20', '40'),
    ('Sekar', '20', '20', '40')
)
```

I want to write the above data to excel file using `xlsxwriter` in python. Expected result should like below

```
  Shankar 100  100  200
  Kumar    50   80  130
  Shiva    20   20   40 
  Sekar    20   20   40
```

Please anyone help me to write the code using `xlsxwriter` in python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out:

```
import xlsxwriter

data  = (('Shankar','100','100','200'),('Kumar','50','80','130'),('Shiva','20','20','40'),('Sekar','20','20','40'))

# Open the workbook and add a worksheet
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('output.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# iterate through your tuple of tuples, and write out each cell 
for row, x in enumerate(data):
    for col, y in enumerate(x):
        worksheet.write(row, col, y)

# Make sure to close the workbook 
workbook.close()
```

Which gives the following *output.xlsx*:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-excel-writer):

```
import pandas as pd

data  = (
    ('Shankar', '100', '100', '200'),
    ('Kumar', '50', '80', '130'),
    ('Shiva', '20', '20', '40'),
    ('Sekar', '20', '20', '40')
)

# Create a dataframe with the data of interest
df = pd.DataFrame(data=list(data), columns=['Name', 'Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'])

# Export the dataframe to a XLSX file, in Worksheet `sheet1`,
# without the index nor the column names of the dataframe
df.to_excel('data.xlsx', sheet_name='sheet1', index=False, header=False)
```

This outputs the following to **data.xlsx**:

[image]

Comment: efficient. why columns names ?

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this:

```
import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('my_excel.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

data = (('Shankar','100','100','200'),('Kumar','50','80','130'),('Shiva','20','20','40'),('Sekar','20','20','40'))

### Iterate over the data and write it out row by row.
for row, line in enumerate(data):
    for col, cell in enumerate(line):
        worksheet.write(row, col, cell)

workbook.close()
```